# Configuration of a header only library (C++)

Tags: c++, config, header-files, configuration-files, lib

I am writing a header-only lib in C++.
Keeping things as simple as possible, the user has to only `#include mylib.h`

In some cases, the (advanced) user may want to **configure the behaviour** of the lib (e.g. error handling, compile-time or runtime checks, debug output, and possibly other stuff)

**Please DO NOT tell me the best way (or even a standard way) to do this, because the question will be put on hold otherwise!!!**

Right now, I have a file 'config.h' as part of my lib, which contains the respecting `#define MYLIB_XYZs` but I realize that this is complete nonsense, as the user needs to modify the lib itself in order to configure.

Comment: Jesus Christ !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep your `config.h` providing the defaults. Just wrap every preprocessor define that is there by a check:

```
#ifndef MYLIB_XYZ
#define MYLIB_XYZ 1 // some sensible default
#endif
```

If the user has set a define themselves, the user-set value will be used. Otherwise, it will fall back to the default provided by you.

Just don't forget to `#include <mylib/config.h>` in every of your header files.

Something like that is used in [Windows headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt), most notably in [ATL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sks11ex0.aspx) which is a Microsoft-provided header-only library.

Comment: The user has to be aware, however, that he has to make his `#defines` BEFORE including the lib! Is this a standard practice?

Comment: They will most likely set the define on the command line `-DMYLIB_XYZ=<smth>`. 
About the 'before' part – well, that's preprocessor. By the time a file is included, every flag is resolved.

Comment: And yes, it is common. Windows headers use the same mechanism: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winprog/using-the-windows-headers#setting-winver-or-_win32_winnt

Comment: Pretty unsatisfactory as I have all positive statements like `MYLIB_CHECKX` which had to be turned into negative ones `MYLIB_DONT_CHECKX` as I want to stick to naked defines without a (redundant) default value.

Comment: Seems like there is no other (less awkward) way, so thx.